# Printing ESC/POS (raw) using windows powershell

Tags: powershell, printing, thermal-printer, escpos

I am trying to print receipts on my Epson TM20ii using ESC/POS commands, sending them to the printer with out-printer' I have tried using both the epson driver and a generic text driver. My problem is that the printer is printing the command instead of executing it. See example

```
"LF" | out-printer -name epson
```

LF is the command for the printer to feed one line, instead of doing so the printer is printing the characters LF

Comment: i just want to point out. this can be a problem with my escpos commands, as i am not super familiar with this language.

Comment: @mklement0 Wouldn't the printer driver initialize the printer on each job/page with own escape sequences and also powershell treat the text as utf16 and add an cr/lf so garbiling the intended codes? With `Out-File` you could add the options `-NoNewLine -Encoding ascii` but Out-Printer doesn't have these.

Comment: @LotPings: Fair points; having never worked with `Out-Printer`, I restricted my comment to pointing out the escape sequence for double-quoted strings. As for PowerShell sending UTF-16LE strings: you'd hope that text is sent in an encoding that the printer understands.

Comment: @IbberChochem: Aside from the potential issues that LotPings mentions: `LF` refers to the newline character (ASCII code `10` / `0xA`), not to the literal string `"LF"`. Simply using line breaks in your text may do the trick (to embed an `LF` char. in a single-line double-quoted string, you can use `\`n`); note that other ESC/POS commands must start with an `ESC` (`27` / `0x1b`) and sometimes a `GS` (`29` / `0x1D`)  character (see http://content.epson.de/fileadmin/content/files/RSD/downloads/escpos.pdf); you can create these with `$esc = [char] 27` and `$gs = [char] 29`.

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out.
as some users commented, the commands are referring to the actual ASCII characters.
this however did not fully solve the problem as for some reason the powershell out-print command was sending the info to the printer in  a way that the printer did not understand to be meant to be interpreted as esc-pos commands. The easiest solution that i found so far is a command line utility called RawPrint.exe which can be found [here](http://www.columbia.edu/~em36/windowsrawprint.html). The tool is very straight forward and i highly recommend it.

Answer (score 0):

You can get [RawPrint.exe](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows/win32/win32-raw-data-to-printer) from Microsoft (source and executable). I feel safer downloading from Microsoft.